# Initiate multiple, simultaneous continuously running scripts via terminal, that continue after terminal session ends

Tags: php, ubuntu, terminal

I have a number of tasks that need to run constantly on the server. As they loop (and therefore aren't meant to come to an end) I'd like to run them in parallel rather than sequentially.

To run one of these scripts I can e.g.

```
 php myscript1.php;
```

In order to run them in parallel I've been using screens. So I create a screen specifically for a script, run it in that screen, then detach create a new one and run the next one in that one.

```
screen -S script1
php myscript1.php;
ctrl-a d
```

repeat

This was fine when there were e.g. 5. But if I restart the server, or want to make changes to how the scripts run it's getting pretty annoying - and there are an increasing number of these small looping tasks running.

I know that any time in terminal I'm working too hard its because I don't know something, so how can I for example run

```
php myscript1.php;  php myscript2.php;  php myscript3.php;
```

So they run simultaneously, and silently (no output)?

**Edit:**
Of note (clarifying thanks to @bossman's comment below) these tasks are of varying and elastic length, and I do not want overlapping instances of the same task running, but I want them to run continuously.

This means a fixed cron job every 10 minutes would not be ideal as some might take e.g. 15 minutes to complete, or 2 minutes. Hence I'm hoping to use loops with a fixed sleep between loops.

Comment: Rather than the loop being in your script, create a cron job (with crontab) for each script and have that cron fire every x seconds or minutes.

Comment: I did wonder about that - but given than I want it to run every 10 minutes say, is there a downside to just building a loop with a 10 minute sleep in it?

Comment: Well, if you had a script that runs via the crontab, it wouldn't matter if you restart the server. The system will start your crons again, also you don't rely on a terminal window always open as it is run in the background as a system process. A cron should just run a script/process, do what it needs to do and close, then repeat (every 10 mins in your case).

Comment: Each script can have its own cron, add as many as you like..

Answer (score 1):

So I figured this out shortly after posting the question, but figured I'd leave it up in case others found it useful.

Here is my approach (though please feel free to let me know if there's a better way.

First start a screen: this is a session within a session that runs even when you close terminal, so this deals with any issue of scripts ending when you leave.

```
screen -S IMMORTALSCRIPTS
```

Having named and attached to that screen, run the commands simultaneously using & to join them typing (in my case)

```
php script1.php & php script2.php & php script3.php
```

They will all run at once, even showing mixed output on this screen, but you can leave the screen via

```
ctrl-a d
```

And return to your regular command line session and continue with anything else, or log out. This suits me because I'd like to be able to later check back on the script output (make sure they're running as expected, not throwing errors) via

```
screen -r IMMORTALSCRIPTS
```

Then on the need to restart them all if I've stopped them or restarted the server I can jump into that screen, tap the up arrow for last command and run the call to all script simultaneously.

Comment: Yes - there is "screen". You might also want to check "tmux".